# asset precompile not generating any json files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, asset-pipeline

I have an app which I want to deploy to Heroku. It works in development, but not when deploying to Heroku.

I am considering this to be an asset precompile issue.

But when I run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`, it doesn't generate anything.

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Please provide more information, what is not working as it is in development? Where did you look for files being generated?

Comment: heroku run bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline

Comment: hey, fixed that earlier with above command. Thanks anyways.
Nazi's are everywhere lol

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you overrided `config.assets.precompile` option and removed default values from it. Check your `config/application.rb` and `config/initializers/assets.rb` files.